# blacklist some domains from requests sessions in python

Tags: python, http, session, python-requests, request

I am using request sessions and I want some of the domains to not form a session pool. Is there any way to do it. Also is following the correct way to do it?

```
blacklist = ["google.com"]
blacklisted = False

def somefunction(imageurl):
    for domain in blacklist:
        if image_url.find(domain)!=-1:
            response = requests.get(image_url) 
            blacklisted = True
            break

    if blacklisted == False:
        response = session.get(image_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with a session you could define an Adapter for all your blacklisted urls something like this:

```py
from requests.adapters import BaseAdapter
from requests.sessions import Session


blacklist = [
    'https://google.com',
    'http://gitlab.com',
] # note, the url scheme is needed


class BlacklistedDomainError(Exception):
    def __init__(message='Blacklisted domain'):
        super(BlacklistedDomainError, self).__init__(message)


class BlacklistAdapter(BaseAdapter):
    def send(
     self,
     request,
     stream=False,
     timeout=None,
     verify=True,
     cert=None,
     proxies=None
):
    raise BlacklistedDomainError()


session = Session()


for prefix in blacklist:
    session.mount(prefix, BlakclistAdapter)


def somefunction(imageurl):
    try:
        response = session.get(imageurl)
    except BlacklistedDomainError:
        return None
    return response
```

I included a custom exception as it is best practice but you could raise any exception.

Be careful I used `domain` here as it is the term you used, but you're really mounting the adapter for a prefix (the session basically checks if the url it tries to reach starts with the string, see [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_modules/requests/sessions/#Session.get_adapter)), that's why the url scheme is important.

See the [requests doc](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) for more info on Adapters.

Comment: Thanks, will this still send requests to blacklisted domains?

Comment: @ShivamTiwari no traffic whatsoever will be going out.

Comment: Actually I need to send requests to those blacklisted domains but just without forming sessions

Comment: @ShivamTiwari I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "forming sessions"

Comment: I need to exclude those domains from pooling. They should not raise exceptions but should send requests without pooling (if I am making sense).

Comment: @ShivamTiwari I do not understand what you mean by pooling ?

Answer (score 0):

```
blacklist = ["google.com"]
blacklisted = False

def somefunction(image_url): #make sure that argument is the same as in next line
    if image_url in blacklist:#check if the url in blacklist without for loop      
          response = requests.get(image_url) 
          blacklisted = True
          break

    if blacklisted == False:
        response = session.get(image_url)
```